# How to select something from a table where something is equal to a variable

Tags: sql, ms-access, visual-studio-2012

I am creating a form that will allow users to add records to a database, the only text field required is a name field. The other fields are drop down boxes populated by other querys from other tables.

It is hard to explain but basically the combo boxes are populated with text but the database fields I am adding the record too is Number (Primary keys from other tables) so I am wandering what the query would be to get the ID number for the choosen item.

ie. TO FILL THE COMBO BOXES I HAVE LINES LIKE THESE.

```
select SpeciesName 
from Species
```

With SpeciesName comes a SpeciesID.

So would it be something like this:

******** speciesSelected in this case would be a variable (`Dim speciesSelected As String = cbxSpeciesName.Item`)

```
select SpeciesID 
from Species 
where SpeciesName = speciesSelected
```

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: Were you looking for [this](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=112974)?

Comment: Unfortunately not unless I read that wrong. I believe my problem lies in the SQL string rather than the variables themselves. Maybe im wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of fetching only the text fields SpeciesName  from the database and loading that into the combobox. Retreive both SpeciesID and SpeciesName from the database and bind both of them to the combobox like SpeciesID as IDfield & SpeciesName as Textfield.

By doing this you can get the speciesId of the species selected directly using the selectedValue property of the control. This can be directly used to store in the database.

Comment: Im sorry thanks for that, but could you possibly show me what you mean in an example.

Comment: Use the select query, SELECT  SpeciesID, SpeciesName FROM Master_Species (Master table of Species). While assigning the data to the combo box 1.Assign combobox.IDField = SpeciesID 2. Combobox.Textfield = Speciesname